# TO_CHAR from Date data type output difference

Tags: sql, oracle, date

```
select CREATED_DATE,to_char(CREATED_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MM') CREATED_DATE_2 from MY_TABLE;

CREATED_DATE            CREATED_DATE_2 
4/20/2020 1:44:57 AM    2020-04-20 01:04
4/20/2020 6:45:55 AM    2020-04-20 06:04
4/21/2020 5:32:57 AM    2020-04-21 05:04
4/21/2020 5:33:45 AM    2020-04-21 05:04
```

Not sure why I see this big difference when using to_char function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the format of month  `MM` instead of Minutes `MI` ,Please use the below

```
  select CREATED_DATE,to_char(CREATED_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') CREATED_DATE_2 from MY_TABLE;
```

Comment: Thank you. Month and minutes are different!